# How to do a “ssh -Y user@host cmd” using Paramiko? Open GUI on remote

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I would like to make automation script using Python and Paramiko.
The client side need to open one GUI app to verify. The app will close after 10 second.

By using terminal command I can achieve it by typing

```
ssh -Y user@host cmd
```

`-Y` is to open the GUI in its own system (client).

But I can't find a a way to do it in Paramiko?

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh -Y` switch enables X11 forwarding.

For an equivalent in Paramiko, see [`Channel.request_x11`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.request_x11).